# How can I make a dynamic table display a value that isn't in the sheet, but its a possible outcome for the variable?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, vlookup, google-query-language

Imagine I have a table 2x2 in Google Sheets:

| variable_1 | variable_2 |
| --- | --- |
| x | 10 |
| y | 13 |
| x | 7 |
| z | 11 |

A Dynamic Table with with **variable_1** in the lines and the **sum(variable_2)** as a value, i would getthe following table:

| variable_1 | sum(variable_2) |
| --- | --- |
| x | 17 |
| y | 13 |
| z | 11 |

Now imagine that the first column is a qualitative variable with the following possible outcomes: x, y, z or w.
Is there a way to, when I make a Dynamic Table, to display the "w" outcome with the value 0?

In R, i would define variable_1 as a factor and, automaticaly, the grouping would include the "w".
I need to get the following table:

| variable_1 | sum(variable_2) |
| --- | --- |
| x | 17 |
| y | 13 |
| z | 11 |
| w | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(D2:D="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(D2:D, QUERY(A1:B, 
 "select A,sum(B) group by A label sum(B)''"), 2, 0), 0)))
```

[image]